# Quantifier elimination in the structure of exponential sums

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logic, model-theory, exponential-sum, quantifier-elimination

We consider the language $L=\{+, -, ' , T, 0, 1\}$

Let $\text{Exp}(\mathbb{C})$ (the exponential sums) be the structure in that we interpret $L$.

We define $\text{Exp}(\mathbb{C})$ as the set of expresions $$\alpha=\alpha_1 e^{\mu_i z}+\dots \alpha_N e^{\mu_N z}$$ where $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\mu_i \in \mathbb{C}$. (The $\mu_i$'s are pairwise distinct.)

Let $T(x)$ be the predicate that $x$ is non-constant.

Consider the expression $$\exists x \left (ax'(z)+bx(z)=y(z) \land T(x) \right ) $$

Since we are looking at the structure $\text{Exp}(\mathbb{C})$, $x$ and $y$ will have the folowing form $$x(z)=\sum_i \beta_i e^{k_i z}, \ \ y(z)=\sum_i \alpha_i e^{\mu_i z}$$

Substituting this at the differential equation we get $$\sum_i \{(a\mu_i +b)\beta_i -\alpha_i \}e^{\mu_i z} =0$$ So that we can solve for $\beta_i$, which means that we can find the solution $x(z)$, it must hold that $$a\mu_i +b \neq 0 \text{ for all } i \text{ for which } \alpha_i \neq 0$$

Is this correct?

So we have to be sure $T(x)$ holds for tthee solutions that we find, right?

How can we do that?

Or do we maybe have to take cases for $a$ and $b$ and find at each case the solution?

Also how can we write the above condition as a quantifier-free formula since there is the index $i$ ?

Comment: Can you either be a bit more precise or give a reference? What exactly is the set $\text{Exp}(\mathbb{C})$? It seems like it's elements are sums of the form $\sum_{i} \beta_ie^{k_iz}$. Are these sums infinite? Are the $\beta_i$ and $k_i$ complex numbers? Is there any convergence requirement? When you say $T(x)$ means "$x$ is non-constant", is this the same as saying $\lnot (x' = 0)$? If so, $T$ is already definable in your language, and there's not need to add a symbol for it. If not, why not? Finally, the formula that you're considering isn't a formula in your language.

Comment: Aside from the obvious typo (you write $x'(x)$ instead of $x'(z)$), thing like $bx$ aren't terms in the language. Did you mean to include a binary function symbol for multiplication (in which case, is $b$ a constant or another exponential sum?) or a family of unary function symbols for multiplication by elements of $\mathbb{C}$ (turning $\text{Exp}(\mathbb{C})$ into a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space)?

Comment: We define $\text{Exp}(\mathbb{C})$ as the set of expresions $$\alpha=\alpha_1 e^{\mu_i z}+\dots \alpha_N e^{\mu_N z}$$ where $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\mu_i \in \mathbb{C}$. (The $\mu_i$'s are pairwise distinct.) $$$$ I corrected the typo at $x'(x)$. $$$$ $a$ and $b$ are constants. Is then $bx$ a term of the language? $$$$ Is the negation definable in the language? $$$$ I think that $T$ is the same as saying $\lnot (x' = 0)$. @AlexKruckman

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Assuming we're using standard first-order logic: 1. terms are built up from the variables and constants in the language ($0$ and $1$ for you) by application of functions. There's no function symbol for "multiplication" or "multiplication by $b$" in your language, so $bx$ is not a term. 2. Negation is one of the basic logical symbols used to build up formulas, so $\lnot (x' = 0)$ is a formula.

Comment: Is $x$ a term of the language? @AlexKruckman

Comment: Yes, $x$ is a variable, and all variables are terms. You should make sure you have a good grasp of the basic definitions of first-order logic (as in the first two chapters of Hodges' (A Shorter) Model Theory, or nearly any other logic textbook) before trying to prove quantifier elimination for complicated structures!

Comment: So since $x$ is a variable, can we write $ax'(z)+bx(z)=y(z)$ or do we have to write $ax'+bx=y(z)$ ? @AlexKruckman

Comment: If you expand the language to allow multiplication by constants, then $\exists x\, (ax' + bx  = y \land T(x))$ is a formula. $x$ and $y$ are variables representing elements of a structure. If it's helpful to write $x(z)$ and $y(z)$ to remind yourself that the elements of $\text{Exp}(\mathbb{C})$ are sums involving $z$, you're welcome to do this informally, but $x(z)$ is *not* part of the first-order syntax in your language. Remember that there are other (nonstandard) models for $\text{Th}(\text{Exp}(\mathbb{C}))$ whose elements are *not* sums involving $z$ in any sense.

Comment: Which set is $\text{Th}(\text{Exp}(\mathbb{C}))$ ? Since $x$ is a term, $x+x$ is also a term, right? Isn't $$\underset{b\text{ times }}{\underbrace{x+x+ \dots +x+x}} =bx$$ also a term? @AlexKruckman

Comment: It's common to use $bx$ as shorthand for $x + \dots + x$ when $b$ is a natural number. You never said that $b$ was a natural number, so I assumed it was a complex number, like your other constants. Again, it's vital that you fully understand basic concepts like terms and formulas (and notions like the theory of a structure $\text{Th}(M)$) in order to understand more complicated things like quantifier elimination. I've voted to close the question.